Python Jira module is not found though its already installed
I have a python file with only this line:
from jira import JIRA

Previously I followed this instruction here: https://jira.readthedocs.io/installation.html
But I still get

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jira'

I tried common things like restarting etc. but nothing worked.
Also tried python -m pip install 'jira[cli]' but only says me that the requirements are already satisfied.
I feel like there's a simple thing missing but I can't get it?

Are you sure you are starting the script through correct interpreter?

@matszwecja I'm feeling so dumb now :D
That was the issue  - thx!
